# How can I restrict one tenant user from another tenant in Umbraco 8?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco8

In Umbraco 8, When I'm Creating multi tenant and base on tenant I'm creating user in user section.

After that When I'm login with tenant admin/user at that time he is able to access all tenant user. which is not correct.

So How can I restrict one tenant user to another tenant ?

How Can I do this from API code?

In previous version Umbraco 7.12.1 its working fine. Tenant user only access their tenant user. (they can see their tenant user only)